# Flash scroll thumbs in safari?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

In cocoa there is an API to "flash" the mac scroll thumbs momentarily at any time in a scroll view.

How can I do this in safari using javascript, on an `overflow:scroll;` element? I want to make the overlay scroll thumbs visible for a second or two, then fade away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up inserting an  on the page in the place where the scroll thumb should be, and after a delay setting it's opacity to 0 with CSS3 transition animations.

I also check for any user scroll event, and hide the image instantly without animation.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me :

```
element.scrollTop = 1;
element.scrollTop = 0;
```